# Redis distributed lock does not take effect

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

I am using `go-redis distributed lock` to realize mutual exclusion access, my server is a single thread server. But at the same time, many requests get the `distributed lock`.

```
func (redisMgrPtr *RedisMgr) getLock(key string) (int32) {
    encodeKey := transcoding.Base64Encode(key)
    _, err := redisMgrPtr.redisClient.SetNX(redisMgrPtr.ctx, 
    encodeKey, 1, TIMEOUT).Result()
    if err != nil {
        return -1
    }
    return 0
}

func (redisMgrPtr *RedisMgr) delLock(key string, sessionId string) {
    encodeKey := transcoding.Base64Encode(key)
    redisMgrPtr.redisClient.Del(redisMgrPtr.ctx, encodeKey)
    Log.Errorf("session[%s] del lock", sessionId)
}
```

Get lock code is like this:

```
func (redisMgrPtr *RedisMgr) GetServer(name string, session string) () {
    for { 
        locRes := redisMgrPtr.getLock(name) 
        if locRes == 0 {
            break
        } else {
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)
            continue
        }
    }
    defer redisMgrPtr.delLock(sceneLock, sessionId)
    Log.Errorf("session[%s] get lock", sessionId)
    // do something
}
```

I find many requests get the lock at the same time, result is

```
2021-09-08T15:05:21.073+0800 session[51776955325] get lock
2021-09-08T15:05:21.073+0800 session[91776955325] get lock
2021-09-08T15:05:21.073+0800 session[71776955325] get lock
```

I think at the same time only one session can get the lock

Comment: Can you post the `getNewDistributeLock` method also?

Comment: @NuLo I have updated

Comment: You could use a package like [redislock](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bsm/redislock) it should simplify things for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the lock function. It does not check if the value existed or not, it just checks the error.

```golang
func (redisMgrPtr *RedisMgr) getLock(key string) (int32) {
    encodeKey := transcoding.Base64Encode(key)
    wasSet, err := redisMgrPtr.redisClient.SetNX(redisMgrPtr.ctx, encodeKey, 1, TIMEOUT).Result()
    if err != nil || !wasSet {
        return -1
    }
    return 0
}
```

... or using a boolean to make it easier to reason about:

```golang
func (redisMgrPtr *RedisMgr) getLock(key string) (ok bool) {
    encodeKey := transcoding.Base64Encode(key)
    wasSet, err := redisMgrPtr.redisClient.SetNX(redisMgrPtr.ctx, encodeKey, 1, TIMEOUT).Result()
    return err == nil && wasSet
}
```

With the boolean version `GetServer` could look like this:

```golang
func (redisMgrPtr *RedisMgr) GetServer(name string, session string) () {
    for { 
        if ok := redisMgrPtr.getLock(name); ok {
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    defer redisMgrPtr.delLock(sceneLock, sessionId)
    Log.Errorf("session[%s] get lock", sessionId)
    // do something
}
```